# Multiple file upload carrierwave mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, carrierwave

I have been having issues with implementing multiple file upload with the `carrierwave-mongoid` gem. Multiple file upload with carrierwave is well documented for `ActiveRecord` but not `Mongoid`. I have tried to mirror the `ActiveRecord` tutorials are much as possible but cannot seem to get it right. My uploader is mounted as follows.

```
class Product
 include Mongoid::Document
 .....
 attr_accessor :product_images, :product_images_cache

 mount_uploaders :product_images, ProductImageUploader
end
```

The main issue that I am having is with saving the uploader instance. In my controller with a pry in the create block, I am able to create a `Product` instance that contains the uploader instances, but when I try to retrieve the Uploader instance via the rails console the array is empty. see below.

```
[22] pry(#<ProductsController>)> @product
=> #<Product _id: 58726dae75e505a9ddc43f20, name: "Post", description: "This is a post\r\n", rating: nil, category_id: 1, seller_id: 1, approved: false, approved_by: nil>

[23] pry(#<ProductsController>)> @product.product_images_urls
=> ["/uploads/tmp/1483894190-43485-0005-7191/download.jpeg", "/uploads/tmp/1483894190-43485-0006-6662/TRACK.jpg"]

[24] pry(#<ProductsController>)> Product.last
=> #<Product _id: 58726dae75e505a9ddc43f20, name: "Post", description: "This is a post\r\n", rating: nil, category_id: 1, seller_id: 1, approved: false, approved_by: nil>

[25] pry(#<ProductsController>)> Product.last.product_images_urls
=> []
```

What is notice here is that the images are not being save in the uploads directory. I have spent quite a bit of time researching this but no leads. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update: This method is currently not supported by `CarrierWave-Mongoid`. My initial thoughts where right the Uploader object was not being created/saved https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid/issues/155. I am currently looking for a workaround for this - any pointer in this direction will be great